# Optimizing for mobile devices don't show correctly

Tags: media-queries

I am trying ( and failing ) to make my website looking good on mobile devices and it just looks wrong. The image is shown right but the box with text is just a thin strip.
Check the image, the box should wrap around the image and text be just as wide as the image.

http://cdn1.cdnme.se/886420/6-3/problem_51612adfddf2b3563ed16d2f.jpg

I'm a novice at this and don't really know what I do but I try to learn by failing, this time though it feels impossible. Is there anything I have done wrong? Is something missing? Is this not the only thing to do to get it to work?
The code for media queries I use is as following:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 }
 #container {
 width:100%; 
 margin: auto; 
 }
  #content {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 }
 #post {
 width: 100%;
 }
 #post img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px 20px 0px;
 float: left;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 }
 #container {
 width:100%; 
 margin: auto; 
 }
  #content {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 }
 #post {
 width: 100%;
 }
 #post img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px 20px 0px;
 float: left;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 }
 #container {
 width:100%; 
 margin: auto; 
 }
  #content {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 }
 #post {
 width: 100%;
 }
 #post img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px 20px 0px;
 float: left;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clear` properties where elements are floated because text-box assumes to be floated along with the image or content proceeding it.

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {

#content {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
clear:both;    /*Important*/
 }

#post img {
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0px 5px 20px 0px;
float: left;
clear:both;    /*Important*/
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px#000000;
 }
}
```